# Evaluate $\int{\frac{x^3}{x^3-3x^2+9x-27}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

So for the equation below I used long division first, and got $\int{(1+\frac{-3x^2+9x-27}{x^3-3x^2+9x-27}})dx$ (So my signs should be the other way around, thank you to Alijah Ahmed for pointing it out, see answer below). Now I'm not sure how to proceed, completing the square would give me something weird, I think maybe using substitution? 
$$\int{\frac{x^3}{x^3-3x^2+9x-27}}dx$$

Update: using partial fractions, $A=1.5, B=1.5, C=-4.5$ and I obtained $x+ \frac{3}{2}ln(x-3)+ \frac{3}{4}ln(x^2+9)-\frac{3}{2}arctan(\frac{x}{3})+C$ as an answer.

Comment: Use partial fractions. Find the zeroes of the denominator and you're done.

Comment: This _begs_ to get factored by grouping: $x^3-3x^2+9x-27$ $=x^2(x-3)+9(x-3)$ $=(x^2+9)(x-3)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @liya77 - you're nearly there! Your partial fraction evaluations are all correct, and the answer looks good, just one error - it should be $\arctan(\frac{x}{3})$ instead of $\arctan(\frac{x}{2})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, use partial fractions.

Also, note that the denominator $x^3-3x^2+9x-27$ factorises to $(x-3)(x^2+9)$ which helps, so you want to find $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that 
$$\frac{A}{x-3}+\frac{Bx+c}{x^2+9}=\frac{\color{red}{+}3x^2\color{red}{-}9x\color{red}{+}27}{(x-3)(x^2+9)}$$
(you had the signs for the numerator after long division wrong - corrections in red in the equation above, i.e. you should have had $\int{(1+\frac{3x^2-9x+27}{x^3-3x^2+9x-27}})dx$)

Comment: I think the signs should remain the same after long division though... only the x^3 and x^3 on the bottom cancel to become 1.

Comment: @liya77 The signs change because you are dividing $x^3$ by $x^3-3x^2+9x-27$. As a check, evaluate $1+\frac{3x^2-9x+27}{x^3-3x^2+9x-27}$.

Comment: Okay, you're right!

Comment: That's okay. I'll leave it to you to proceed further.